# How to get class name and use it?

Tags: java, class

```
final List<Integer> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
final List<Number> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();

String className1 = arrayList1.get(0).getClass().getName();
Class<?> classType1 = Class.forName(className1);

String className2 = arrayList2.get(0).getClass().getName();
Class<?> classType2 = Class.forName(className2);
```

And here is the problem:

```
if (arrayList1.get(0) instanceof classType2) {}
```

**classType2** connot be resolved to a type.
How i can fix that?

Comment: You know that `getClass()` returns a `Class` right? Either use `instanceof` or compare the `Class` objects, but don't try to use both.

Comment: `classType2.isInstance(arrayList1.get(0))` based on documentation of [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) (and why get the name of `Class`and then use `forName`?  just `classType2 = arrayList2.get(0).getClass()` )

Comment: JLS reference https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will always give a Compilation error because as soon as the compiler compiles the Java source into Java bytecode it applies a process known as [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which converts all generic code into non-generic code, making impossible to distinguish among T types at runtime. The type used with instanceof has to be reifiable,

Please see the example shown in the [link](https://riptutorial.com/java/example/12864/use-of-instanceof-with-generics)